# How to recognise the user session/id without logging in?

Tags: python, flask

I´m working on a web page using flask.

All of my templates have this "@login_required" in order to make sure the user logged in every time they want to access to their accounts.

I coded a template that the user can easily generate in their accounts. I want to make others be able to see it without having to login, only if they have a certain link to that template (this template has specific user information).

The problem comes when I have to do this. In order to make people be able to see an specific template generated by the user, I eliminate the "@login_required" from that template, but now I cant pass the user information (phone, email, etc.). I cant display the user data to the person who opens the link because I cant access the user database, the program cant recognize whose data to display. Whenever someone want to access that specific template, the program does not recognise who the "user_id" is because he/she has never logged in. But I dont want them to log in.

So my question is: is there a way I can access an specific user session without having to log in? Thanks in advance.

Comment: having users with no login get session-IDs? that sounds like you might as well have no login at all and all user data open to the public ...

Comment: @garglblarg I would like the general public to be able to access an specific user template. Not all of them. And they only can access it through an specific link provided by the user

Comment: i'm just sayin: leaving an opening _will_ be exploited ...

Comment: @garglblarg What do you recommend me doing?

Comment: don't try to work around things like login mechanics. your users will be not thanking you, after their data was not stolen ;>

Comment: @garglblarg The idea was to make the user inputs only the data they want to share to the public